# struts-config.xml file - purpose of input

Tags: input, struts, configuration-files

I am new to struts. I am wondering what input variable here signifies. After some googling, the only conclusive piece of info was this:

*Input: The physical page (or another ActionMapping) to which control should be  forwarded when validation errors exist in the form bean.*

Is there any other use for the input parameter besides the case of an error occurring?

```
<action
   roles="somerole"
   path="some/path"
   type="some.java.class"
   name="somename"
   input="someInput"
   scope="request"
   validate="false"
   parameter="action">
   <forward name="success" path="some/path"/>
   <forward name="download" path="/another/path"/>
</action>
```

Comment: The only time your page is going to get forwarded to the jsp defined under _input_ when there is a validation error in the form `somename`. So you are correct in your understanding of the _input_ attribute here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, although you're correct that it's primarily a forward for failed validation.

The input has a dedicated method to return it: `ActionMapping.getInputForward()`. This can be used in custom (Java-based) validation to return to the input page.

It can also be used to identify a "landing" page: an action base class or custom request processor might send `GET` requests to the `input` forward, and process `POST`s normally.